# Cosmology: Dimensionless density parameter calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology

**The question**:

Given an FRW model dominated by a perfect cosmological fluid with eqn of state P=$\omega \rho$ for $\omega$ =constant.

Along with the density parameter $\Omega (t) = \frac{ \rho (t) }{ \rho_{crit} (t) } $ where $\rho_{crit} (t) = \frac{ 3H^2}{8\pi G}$.

Show that $\frac{d\Omega}{d\ln{a} } = (1+3\omega)\Omega(\Omega - 1) $

**My thoughts**

I have tried a few things including using the chain rule $\frac{d\Omega}{d\ln{a}} = \frac{d\Omega}{da} \frac{da}{d\ln{a}} $. But not sure on exact way to approach.

Any useful hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to know how $\rho$ depends on $a$.

Comment: Cheers, forgot to say I have solved it.